# How to update rows based on condition in spark-sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am working on spark-sql for data preparation.

The problem I am facing is after getting the result of sql query. How should I update rows based on the If-then-else condition.

*What I am doing*

```
  val table_join = sqlContext.sql(""" SELECT a.*,b.col as someCol
  from table1 a LEFT JOIN table2 b 
  on a.ID=b.ID """)
table_join.registerTempTable("Table_join")
```

Now when I have final joined table which is in df format. How should I update rows?

```
//Final filtering operation
val final_filtered_table = table_join.map{ case record=> 
  if(record.getAs[String]("col1") == "Y" && record.getAs[String]("col2") == "") record.getAs[String]("col2")="UNKNOWN" 
  else if (record.getAs[String]("col1") == "N") record("col1")=""
  else record
}
```

In the above map the if syntax works properly but the moment I apply the update condition to modify It gives me error.

But why the below query is working

```
 if(record.getAs[String]("col1") == "Y" && record.getAs[String]("col2") == "") "UNKNOWN"
```

But the moment I change `"UNKNOWN"` to `record.getAs[String]("col2")="UNKNOWN"` It gives me error at at `.getAs`

Another approach I tried is this:

```
val final_filtered_sql = table_join.map{row => 
  if(row.getString(6) == "Y" && row.getString(33) == "") row.getString(6) == "UNKNOWN" 
  else if(row.getString(6) == "N") row.getString(6) == ""
  else row
}
```

This is working but is this the right approach as I should not call the columns by their no's but instead their names. What approach should I follow to get names of the column and then update ??

Please help me regarding this. What syntax should I do to update rows based on the condition in `dataframe` in `spark-sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`record.getAs[String]("col2")="UNKNOWN"` won't work because `record.getAs[String](NAME)` will return a `String` which doesn't have a `=` method and assigning a new value to a string doesn't make sense.

`DataFrame` records don't have any setter methods because `DataFrames` are based on `RDD` which are immutable collections, meaning you cannot change their state and that's how you're trying to do here.

One way would be to create a new `DataFrame` using `selectExpr` on `table_join` and put that `if/else` logic there using `SQL`.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. Are you suggesting this syntax`val filter_sql = sqlContext.sql(""" select col1,col2,col3,if(col2='Y' and col4='','UNKNOWN',if(col2='N','',)) from table_join""")`

Comment: @agnes yes you can do it directly like this when doing `sql` or you can use something similar called `selectExpr` on your `table_join` dataframe https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#selectExpr(java.lang.String...)